# Navigational bar (menu options at bottom) will also work if I use Action Bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I like to know that If i added Action bar then Navigation bar at the bottom will display menu options or not?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That depends upon your `android:targetSdkVersion` value. Ideally, you will set that to be `14` or higher, in which case you will not get the ... in the navigation or system bar. If, however, your `android:targetSdkVersion` is set between `11` and `13`, you will get the ... in the navigation bar.

See [this blog post](http://commonsware.com/blog/2012/06/08/removing-rogue-menus.html) from last year for more information, along with the classic ["Say Goodbye to the Menu Button" post](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2012/01/say-goodbye-to-menu-button.html) from the Android Developers Blog.

Comment: If i set the android:targetSdkVersion to 10 then "Navigational bar (menu options at bottom) will also work if I use Action Bar"

Comment: @Android: You won't have an action bar if you set `android:targetSdkVersion` to 10 or lower.

Comment: If i set android:targetSdkVersion to 11 then Menu options are not appear at the bottom in ICS.Please help me why its so..

Comment: @Android: Since the objective is for "menu options" to *not* be in the navigation/system bar, it sounds like you are doing fine.

Comment: So will it be "If i added Action bar then Navigation bar at the bottom will display menu options or not?"

Comment: @Android: The objective of any serious Android developer in 2013 and beyond, for an app with an action bar, is to not have ... in the navigation/system bar. Users with devices that have a MENU button can press the MENU button to access the overflow; users without MENU buttons will have a ... *in the action bar*, not in the navigation/system bar. All of this is covered in the "Say Goodbye to the Menu Button" post that I linked to in my answer.

Comment: Please give answer in yes & no "If i added Action bar then Navigation bar at the bottom will display menu options or not?" –"

Comment: Your question cannot be answered "in yes & no". There are many Android developer support sites on the Internet, offering help in a variety of languages. You may have better luck with a site that is in a language that is more comfortable for you. I have several such sites listed at http://www.andglobe.com. In this answer, I have pointed you to multiple English-language resources explaining the behavior of the action bar and navigation/system bar -- perhaps other sites in other languages will help you understand what is written there.